# Is it possible to put only one option on a ternary expression?

Tags: c#, dictionary, syntax, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I am just curious if this is possible or is there a way for this to become a valid syntax for C#:

```
expression == value ? /*do nothing here, or put some empty block like { ; } */ : SomeClass.SomeMethod();
```

**Edit**: For an in-depth discussion and more information, I thought this block would work (if the dictionary key tested does not exist, it adds the dictionary. else, it would skip):

```
(!packageDict.ContainsKey(desc)) ? packageDict.Add(desc, subtotal) : /*does nothing*/;
```

Comment: No, it is not possible. Use `if` statement to do that... another alternative is by having "default" value or simply return itself on one of the two results.

Comment: @Ian this could be an answer, btw.

Comment: You have to *return* something, may be `value`  itself, default value etc.

Comment: why you need that? explain the requirement(by providing more code) .. may be there has some tricky way!!

Comment: @Moumit code added for more information and further discussion/explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By looking at your code snippet, it simply makes no sense to use a ternary operation here.

All you can do is:

```
if (!packageDict.ContainsKey(desc))
    packageDict.Add(desc, subtotal)
```

Comment: Exactly what I did to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No, and that makes sense. What would `expression` be in your no-operation action? `null`? The same as it was? How should the compiler know that?

This for example will leave the variable unset. What is `expression` here?

```
var expression == value ? : SomeClass.SomeMethod();
```

Just make explicit what you expect, so either this:

```
expression == value ? null : SomeClass.SomeMethod();

expression == value ? default(Expression) : SomeClass.SomeMethod();
```

Or this to keep the variable the same when `value` is true:

```
expression == value ? expression : SomeClass.SomeMethod();

if (!value) expression = SomeClass.SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `IF` statement (it is also the most readable option).

An alternative is to use default for your type (e.g. `null` for reference types or `default(value_type)` for value types. E.g:

```
expression == value ? (int?) null : SomeClass.SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and makes little sense.

The ternary operator is supposed to *return a value based on a condition*. This is very important. You can treat it as something like this:

```
public static SomeType TernaryOperator<T>(Predicate<T> condition) {
    if (condition()) {
        return something;
    } else {
        return somethingElse;
    }
}
```

So if you remove the `return something` part, will the code compile? The answer is an undoubtedly  no. What *will* the method return if the condition is true?

The same thing applies to ternary operators. If the condition evaluates to true, what will the whole expression return? It is undefined!

In fact, having this idea in the first place is pretty strange. Why would you want to do that? You can just use an if statement.

```
if (condition) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    //something
}
```

Of course, you can always do it like this:

```
if (!condition) {
    // something
}
```

to remove the useless curly braces.

When you encounter this kind of situation next time, just use an if statement. It is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

**The tricky way!!**

> as per discussion in comment section

this is very basic requirement when working with `Dictionary` .. you need to check these type of logical test may times .. so i would like to suggest you to write some `extension methods` which can make program smother ..

```
public static class Extended
{
    public static void AddKeyIfNotExists<T, V>(this IDictionary<T,V> dictionary, T key, V Value)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dictionary.Add(key, Value);
        }             
    }
}
```

Later you can use it in your `program seamlessly`

```
Dictionary<string,decimal> packageDict= new Dictionary<string,decimal>();

packageDict.AddKeyIfNotExists("demoKey",500);//will add in dictionary
packageDict.AddKeyIfNotExists("demoKey1", 200);//will add in dictionary
packageDict.AddKeyIfNotExists("demoKey", 6);//will not add in dictionary
```